# I'm getting an error "TypeError: searchField.toLowerCase is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**    I'm getting an error  "TypeError: searchField.toLowerCase is not a function" when trying to run this code whereas the code is compiling successfully**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CardList from '../Components/CardList';
import SearchBox from '../Components/SearchBox';
//import { robots } from './robot';
import './App.css';
import Scroll from '../Components/Scroll';
import ErrorBoundry from '../Components/ErrorBoundry';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { searchChange } from '../actions'     
 
 
 
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {searchField:state.searchField}
 }
 
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return {
        searchField:(event) => dispatch(searchChange(event.target.value))
    }
 }
 
 class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            robots:[]
        }   
    }
    
 
 
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(respond =>{
            return respond.json()
        }).then(users =>{
 
            this.setState({robots:users})
        })
    }
    
    render(){
        const { searchField, onSearchChange } = this.props;
        const filterRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots =>{
            //trying to search robot with either upper case or lower case
            return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
        });
 
        return(
            <div className="tc">
            <h1 className="head"> Robo Friend App</h1>
            <div>
            <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange}/>
            </div>
 
            <Scroll>
            <ErrorBoundry>
            <CardList robots={filterRobots} />
            </ErrorBoundry>
            </Scroll>
            </div>
            )
    }
    
 }
 
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: toLowerCase() works on string. It looks like you are trying to do toLowerCase() on searchField, which doesn't have type as string.

Comment: Is `searchField` definitely a string? Can you log it to the console and tell us? `console.log(searchField);`

Comment: Check my answer for the fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **mapDispatchToProps** code block from

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
      searchField:(event) => dispatch(searchChange(event.target.value))
  }
}
```

into

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
      onSearchChange:(event) => dispatch(searchChange(event.target.value))
  }
}
```

The problem in your implementation is you are using the same(prop) name for both mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps and in this case, later overwrites the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your  `mapDispatchToProps` function is overriding the `searchField` prop that is defined in `mapStateToProps`. So the `searchField` prop is actually a function instead of a string.

Answer (score -1):

Your `filterRobots` function tries to run while `searchField` is still undefined

Try checking `searchField` value before running the filter like this

```
const filterRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots =>{
      
       //*** add the next line
      if(!searchField) return undefined
       //trying to search robot with either upper case or lower case
      return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
  });
```

This ensures that this line

```
return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
```

only runs if `searchField` has a value

Comment: You don't need to return `undefined`, you can just `return;`. By the very logic, it will default to be `undefined` anyway.

Comment: @GROVER. You are right just for a new user it may be confusing to see a blank return